# Remove parent tag (without removing children) with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using `ElementTree` to modify the following xml:

```
<li>
  <p>Some stuff goes in <b>bold</b> here </p>
</li>
```

I would like to remove all `<p>` from my `<li>` elements but keep the contents.

Like this:

```
<li>Some stuff goes in <b>bold</b> here</li>
```

I am currently using the following code, which works in simple cases (no text/tail, etc....):

```
# strip <p> from <li> elements
liElements = rootNode.findall('.//li')
for elem in liElements:
    para = elem.find(".//p")
    for child in para:
        elem.append(child)
    elem.text = para.text
    elem.remove(para)
```

There must an easier way to just strip a formatting tag.... I hope?

Comment: Looks like you are processing HTML instead; unless it is really XHTML, use a HTML parser. The [BeautifulSoup HTML library](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/) has a [`.unwrap()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) for just this task.

Comment: My example uses HTML tags but my content is not just HTML. It has mostly custom tags. But I imagine it's all the same to a parser... all of my parsing code (there's a lot) uses ElementTree so I'd like to find a way to use that before converting to a different parsing library

Comment: With `ElementTree` there is no easier method, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way is to *not* use ElementTree to process HTML, but to use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead; the library handles unwrapping explicitly through the [`.unwrap()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap):

```
for elem in soup.find_all('li'):
    for para in elem.find_all('p'):
        para.unwrap()
```

Comment: Yup, no easier way with ElementTree. I've ported some section of my code over to BeautifulSoup... IMHO it's slightly nicer to use. Pretty close to lxml though.